# Multiple data used ajax request in java

Tags: java, ajax, spring

I have an ajax that requesting a multiple info from the server side.

**Example:**

1. username
2. password
3. name
4. gender
5. and etc.

This info will come from the database. But I tried to return a bean and using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) return it as json object, from my servlet I did:

```
return new Gson().toJson( userBean );
```

But when i try to access this through:

```
$.post('../admin/moderator_getInfo.do',
    { anId : id },
    function( data ) {
        console.log( data.username );
        console.log( data.name );
    },
    'json')
});
```

It seems the data is unidentified. In `data.username`, `username` is a property of the bean

**My question is. How can to access bean in response or I bean is not the proper way to do this. What should I use to transfer the data?**

NOTE: I'm sure that the bean is not null.

Comment: console.log(data) what you get ???????

Comment: @rajeshkakawat got it. Thanks for your help. I'm accessing it wrong.

Comment: @rajeshkakawat can you post the answer? So I can repay you at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove "});" in JS example.

I didn't use Gson with Spring, but I wrote an example controller method with "@ResponseBody String":

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/p/ajax/mytest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String myTest(@RequestParam Long anId) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    result.put("status", "success");
    result.put("value4", "success");    
    result.put("username", "success");
    result.put("myanId", anId);

    return result.toString();
}
```